# AlertDialog If/Else to check against system services?

Tags: java, android, gps, android-alertdialog, application-settings

Quick question, I've got a method where an Alert Dialog is built and want to call it when it detects that WIFI or GPS on the android device is not enabled.

So essentially:

If: The device does not have wifi or GPS //Don't know how this code is
{
Built the alert dialog
}
Else:
{
Don't worry and do nothing
}

Any Ideas?

My code:

```
 public void checkPhoneStatus(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
        alertDialog.setMessage("We've noticed your WIFI and GPS are off. Are you okay? Do you want to call the Authorities?");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.about);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); //Runs the intent - starts the phone call
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:77777777")); //Number set for the phone call
                startActivity(callIntent); //Start the intent
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please go to Settings and enable WIFI or GPS!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to check if WiFi is enabled:

```
public boolean isWiFiEnabled(Context context) {
     WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     return wifi.isWifiEnabled();
}
```

To check if GPS is enabled you can use:

```
public boolean isGPSEnabled (Context context){
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

EDIT: I'd use it this way:

```
if (!isWiFiEnabled(this) || !isGPSEnabled(this)) {
    displayConnectivityProblemDialog();
}
```

Please note that I've renamed your `checkPhoneStatus()` method to `displayConnectivityProblemDialog()`. Not necessary, but a matter of taste :)

Comment: Could you show me using my code, my IF/ELSE statements are causing me some issues...

Comment: Edited the post to include a sample usage :)

Answer (score 0):

the design sounds inexact.

what I would do:

1) have a background process that checks that the internet/wifi is up with a ping every n seconds (ie; n = 120)

2) if the ping fails, *then* show the dialog.

and only build the dialog right before you *know* you want to show it.

you need to separate the business logic from the ui; it leads to a much cleaner design.

Comment: I initially wanted to do this, but was not to sure how to proceed, so thought just a simple check if it was enabled/disabled would suffice. Could you show me me how this would go about working or a link?